# Retagging UI is still enabled on uneditable locked questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, locked-questions

The retagging interface is still enabled for questions which have been locked and can not be edited. Attempts to retag result in an error.

> [image]

In these cases, the retagging interface should be disabled as the editing interface is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch, thanks. Fixed in the next build.